# CallbackFlow trysend() not working with Amplify auth signin function

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify, repository-pattern

In my android project, I'm using CallbackFlow to get responses from the repository to ViewModel. at the function login(), I'm trying to log in with Amplify using auth, I am tryingsend() the result but get nothing :

Repository.kt:

```
override fun login(username: String, password: String): Flow<DataState<AuthSignInResult>> = callbackFlow {
    try {
        Amplify.Auth.signIn(username, password,
            { result ->
                trySend(DataState.Success(result))
                channel.close()
            },
            {
                trySend(DataState.Failure(it))
                channel.close()
                Log.e("AuthQuickstart", "Failed to sign in", it)
            }
        )

        awaitClose{

        }

    }catch (e : Exception){
        trySendBlocking(DataState.Failure(e))
        channel.close()
    }

}
```

ViewModel.kt:

```
fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        databaseRepository.login(username,password).collect{
            _userDataState.value = it
        }
    }

}
```

could you please help me to know about this problem ?

Comment: Flow is for a sequence of changing data so it doesn’t really fit the concept of attempting a login. It should just be a suspend function that you can create using `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. As for why your code doesn’t work, I can’t spot the error that would cause it but I’m not familiar with Aws. `awaitClose` should be outside the try/catch though.

Comment: Thank you @Tenfour04, suspendCoroutine  works for me.